# What possible explanations are there for a dramatic change in vegetation appearance in Sentinel 2 data?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, classification, land-cover, sentinel-2

I'm looking at land cover in an area of South East Asia. I pulled down Sentinel 2 imagery for Feb 2017, and used the QGIS SCP plugin to complete the land cover analysis, as per this tutorial: https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2016/09/basic-tutorial-2.html. Wanting to better understand which areas of lesser growth were plant growth recovering from cultivation, and what were otherwise sparse forest, I took a look at some older satellite data, only to find it looked very different. I've included examples below using using Sentinel bands 4,8 and 12, all of which were processed in identical ways.

If this is indeed just a difference in the visual output of SCP/QGIS, I would love to know how to get them more comparable.

Jan 2016
[image]

Jan 2017
[image]

Feb 2017
[image]

Comment: did you check some other sources like google earth to see if this might me some fire incidents or intensification of land use?

Comment: have you tried overlaying a NDVI band?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the location of study area? My guess would be snow cover

Comment: To be clear, this is an RGB composite of 4-8-12? (R:band 4, G:band 8 and B: band 12)

Comment: @firefly-orange snow or cloud! you could also try using a [NDSI](http://spaceanalyzer.com/index.php/normalized-difference-snow-index-ndsi)

Comment: Are these Sentinel-2 L2A products calibrated to bottom of atmosphere reflectance?

Comment: Thanks all. Google earth does suggest that there might be some increase in overall agricultural usage. I expected to see areas of cultivation in bright pink, then fading to dull purple over time. This is beautifully the case in the first two images. But it confuses me that the area to the above right of the centre started as very dull, washed out colour, and then became a stronger purple in the most recent image.

Comment: This is in Western Myanmar, so no snow, and from checking the other bands and the fact that there is consistency between the various months, I'm sure it's not cloud. These are S2A products converted to reflectance through the SCP plugin for QGIS. And yep, bands 4, 8 and 12. SCP excludes 1, 9 and 10 from the band set, so internally this is 3-7-10 because of the omissions. I'm fairly new to this so don't yet know the background to that. I'll try adding a NVDI calculation band - is there any good introductory guidance online as to how I would best interpret that?

Comment: @Will check out the following link, [NDVI](http://spaceanalyzer.com/index.php/normalized-difference-vegetation-index-ndvi) is a widely used  measure in remote sensing, you should be able to find plenty of resources online fairly easily. It's a very simple band ratio so it won't be able to tell you _that_ much!
Another place where you might find comparable (VIS) images is [Planet](https://www.planet.com/), they've got ~190 'doves' in orbit that produce daily coverage - cloud cover may be an issue though, and I haven't worked out how to get 1 daily image instead of the monthly composites

Comment: Could you supply the coords to the area in the imagery?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggesting, there are several explanations for this phenomena.

The most curial part is where in South East Asia is the location exactly.

I make my assumption based on [this ESA source](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/overview),  [the German wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-2#Spektralkan.C3.A4le_von_Sentinel-2) for sentinel 2 ([here is the English one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-2#Instruments)) and my general knowledge of Remote sensing.

1. It could be a change in the way images are processed but I did not find any hints that there was a change.
2. Comparing the images from 2016 and 2017 this could indicate an intensification of agricultural use of the area.
3. The change between Jan. and Feb. might be harvest - or planting season.
4. It could also either a fire event or snow fall. (Again depends on where we are to rule out this point)
5. Change in the atmosphere because band 12 can be used to get aerosols and band 8 for water vapor(indicated in german wiki articel not in the english one).

Comment: Thanks for this. This is in Western Myanmar, so no snow fall. I'll have to investigate the likelihood of fire up there - particularly if farmers have been using slash and burn to clear ground. But what interests me is that the dull purple areas in the first images are much richer purple in the final one, where as I expected them to fade further over time, or bright pink if they were being cleared again for cultivation. So in the absence in changes to the Sentinel image processing, it could well be options 2, 3 or 5. Perhaps I'll try to compare against LANDSAT imagery.

Comment: If the trees have leaves at that time, it may be the attack of some insects